The position of ONLY in a conditional sentence
How would we differentiate between the two?
A. Only if he comes, will I go.


B. If he comes, only then will I go.

Do the two really differ in meaning? How?

These are fairly stiff and formal ways of expressing the idea, BTW. In casual conversation it would be "I'll go only if he comes".

@TimR Or rather, technically misplaced but far more common in my hearing: "I'll only go if he comes."

This would make it a horse race: "I'll go, but only if he comes".

They do not differ in meaning, only in structure.
With one caveat: "then" is clearly intended causally here, but it can also be understood temporally. Thus, the second sentence could be interpreted as presupposing that the speaker intends to go, but is waiting till this other person comes. In the first sentence, this presupposition does not exist.
Even this difference is very subtle and arguably immaterial because, practically, either way the speaker will not go (whatever their intention was) if the other person doesn't come.
Also see the alternative phrasings in the comments on the question:

I'll go only if he comes.


I'll only go if he comes.


I'll go, but only if he comes.

Despite being technically analyzable as different, these are all said with the exact same force of meaning.

They do differ.
The second phrase would be used to indicate that I will only go once he has come (in the temporal sense).
The first phrase indicates that I will go if he comes, regardless (theoretically) if he has come yet or not. (the second phrase can, and often is, interpreted the same way - but this phrase cannot cover the interpretation of the second phrase.)
To give an example that highlights the distinction, imagine if I knew with 100% certainty (time machine, a solemn vow, a one-way downhill trip, whatever) that he will come. However, I suffer from social anxiety and need my unreliable emotional-support dog there in order to be there.
Which of the two phrases would I use?

woops @Luke Sawczac I didn't read your answer properly, just the opening line... I'll leave my answer in place though because I think it emphasises the point more. Yours is a better answer though
